# Web Scraping multiple pages in series using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

How can I scrape html data of 70 pages? I was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232353/scrape-html-table-with-multiple-pages-using-r) but I am stuck at the function of the general method section.

```
#attempt

library(purrr)

url_base <-"https://secure.capitalbikeshare.com/profile/trips/QNURCMF2Q6"

map_df(1:70, function(i) {

cat(".")

pg <- read_html(sprintf(url_base, i))   

data.frame( startd=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".ed-table__col_trip-start-date")), 
endd=html_text(html_nodes(pg,".ed-table__col_trip-end-date")),
duration=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".ed-table__col_trip-duration"))
)
}) -> table



#attempt 2 (with just one data column)

url_base <-"https://secure.capitalbikeshare.com/profile/trips/QNURCMF2Q6"


map_df(1:70, function(i) {

page %>% html_nodes(".ed-table__item_odd") %>% html_text()

}) -> table
```

Comment: Your urls should have a parameter somewhere, that represents the currrent page number and then you should paste it with the `url_base` to generate the actual url. It seems right now that you are trying to access the same url 70 times

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is happening in the answer you referenced, so I am providing an example very similar task to what you want to do.

- Go to a web page collect information, add it a dataframe and then move to the next page.

I used this code created to track my answers posted here to stackoverflow:

```
login<-"https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f"

library(rvest)
pgsession<-html_session(login)
pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[2]]
filled_form<-set_values(pgform, email="*****", password="*****")
submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)

#pre allocate the final results dataframe.
results<-data.frame()  

for (i in 1:5)
{
  url<-"http://stackoverflow.com/users/**********?tab=answers&sort=activity&page="
  url<-paste0(url, i)
  page<-jump_to(pgsession, url)
  
  #collect question votes and question title
  summary<-html_nodes(page, "div .answer-summary")
  question<-matrix(html_text(html_nodes(summary, "div"), trim=TRUE), ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)

  #find date answered, hyperlink and whether it was accepted
  dateans<-html_node(summary, "span") %>% html_attr("title")
  hyperlink<-html_node(summary, "div a") %>% html_attr("href")
  accepted<-html_node(summary, "div") %>% html_attr("class")
  
  #create temp results then bind to final results 
  rtemp<-cbind(question, dateans, accepted, hyperlink)
  results<-rbind(results, rtemp)
}

#Dataframe Clean-up
names(results)<-c("Votes", "Answer", "Date", "Accepted", "HyperLink")
results$Votes<-as.integer(as.character(results$Votes))
results$Accepted<-ifelse(results$Accepted=="answer-votes default", 0, 1)
```

The loop in this case is limited to only 5 pages, this needs to change to fit your application.  I replaced the user specific values with ******, hopefully this will provide some guidance for you problem.