# Trying to Webscrape My Own Stackoverflow Profile

Tags: html, r, xml, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the question links (i.e. the url link to every questions I have ever asked) on my own stackoverflow profile (e.g. on math stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1024449/antonoyaro8).

```
I am using the following code:

library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(XML)



my_list = list()

for (i in 1:3)

{

url_i = paste0("https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1024449/antonoyaro8?tab=questions&sort=newest&page=", i)

   resource_i <- GET(url_i)
   parse_i <- htmlParse(resource_i)
   links <- list(xpathSApply(parse, path="//a", xmlGetAttr, "href"))  
   final_i = grep("questions/\\d+", links[[1]], value = TRUE)

my_list[[i]] = data.frame(i,final_i)

}

mathoverflow_antono = do.call(rbind.data.frame , my_list)

saveRDS(mathoverflow_antono , "mathoverflow_antono.RDS")
```

**This works, but it is returning the links for my stackoverflow website, not my math stackexchange website.**

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd recommend using the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to solve my problem in the meantime?

Comment: Maybe my answer here might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738052/web-scraping-multiple-pages-in-series-using-r/39778813#39778813

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# create empty dataframe
my_list = tibble(topics=as.character(),url=as.character())

for (i in 1:3) {
  
  topics <- session(url_i) %>%
    html_elements(xpath = "//*/div[2]/h3/a") %>%
    html_text()
  
  url <- session(url_i) %>%
    html_elements(xpath = "//*/div[2]/h3/a/@href") %>%
    html_text()
  
# added "https://math.stackexchange.com/" before your URL, delete if necessary
  my_scraped_list <- tibble(topics=topics,url=paste0("https://math.stackexchange.com/",URL))
  
# add newly scraped dataframe to your existing dataframe
  my_list <- my_list %>%
    add_row(my_scraped_list)
}
```

Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: @ KKW: thank you so much! Do you know what was wrong with my approach?

Comment: links <- list(xpathSApply(parse, path="//a", xmlGetAttr, "href")). `parse` should be `parse_i` I was able to use your code to get the same result after i changed to `parse_i`. You may have saved `parse` variable under another task. Hope that helps