# R: Using the Stackoverflow API in R

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I am trying to get a list for the links of all questions I have asked on StackOverflow. Earlier, I learned how to do this without using an API ([Trying to Webscrape My Own Stackoverflow Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74131300/trying-to-webscrape-my-own-stackoverflow-profile)), now I am trying to do the same thing with using the API.

Doing some research, I found out this API link: "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/13203841/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&page=

Here is my attempt to perform this:

**Approach 1: Using a For Loop**

```
library(jsonlite)

my_list = list()

for (i in 1:25)
{

url_i <- paste0("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/13203841/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&page=", i)

response_i <- GET(url_i)
content_i <- content(response_i, "text")

data_i <- fromJSON(content_i)
questions_i <- data_i$items$link

my_list[[i]] = questions_i

print(i)

}
final <- do.call(rbind, my_list)
```

**Approach 2: Using a WHILE loop**

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

base_url <- "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/13203841/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&page="
page_num <- 1
my_list <- list()

while (TRUE) {
  url <- paste0(base_url, page_num)
  response <- GET(url)
  content <- content(response, "text")
  data <- fromJSON(content)
  
  if (length(data$items) == 0) {
    break
  }
  
  questions <- data$items$link
  my_list[[page_num]] <- questions
  page_num <- page_num + 1
  
  print(page_num)
}

final <- do.call(rbind, my_list)
```

**My Question:** Am I doing this correctly? Will this also work for my mathoverflow profile https://math.stackexchange.com/users/791334/stats-noob?tab=questions&sort=newest&page=1 ?

**Note:** Here is how I would get links from my mathoverflow profile

```
library(rvest)
base_url <- "https://math.stackexchange.com/users/791334/stats-noob?tab=questions&sort=newest&page="
all_links <- c()

for(page_num in 1:11) {
    url <- paste0(base_url, page_num)
    page <- read_html(url)
    links <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//a[@class='s-link' and starts-with(@href, '/questions/')]") %>% html_attr("href")
    links <- paste0("https://math.stackexchange.com", links)
    all_links <- c(all_links, links)
}

all_links <- all_links[!grepl("Tagged", all_links)]
all_links
```