# readHTMLTable returns incomplete data set

Tags: r

There was a question a few days ago from a user that brought up something fairly interesting. Please see  [How to use readHTMLTable without cutting off first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230687/how-to-use-readhtmltable-without-cutting-off-first-row) for the original question.

I've been somewhat intrigued by the strange behavior being exhibited by the `header` argument in `readHTMLTable` (package `XML`).  Before I go any further, I can confirm that I have been through the documentation and it states that

> "The methods attempt to do some heuristic computations to determine
>   the header labels for the columns, the name of the table, etc."

Okay, so I can expect that the `header` argument may not always return an optimal result.  By the way, does that only apply to the header argument? Or might the entire table not be optimal?

Well, after a bit of investigation, I find that the complete table will not be optimal. It will only be returned complete when `header = FALSE`.  Setting `header = TRUE` or leaving it blank (`header = NA`) results in a table that is **missing the first row of data**.

The data table for this problem is at [NFL.com](http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?archive=false&conference=null&statisticPositionCategory=FIELD_GOAL_KICKER&season=2013&seasonType=REG&experience=&tabSeq=1&qualified=false&Submit=Go)

Let's have a look...

```
URL <- "http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?archive=false&conference=null&statisticPositionCategory=FIELD_GOAL_KICKER&season=2013&seasonType=REG&experience=&tabSeq=1&qualified=false&Submit=Go"
library(XML)
## missing first row of table
head(readHTMLTable(URL)$result[1:10], 3)  
##   V1             V2  V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
## 1  1  Justin Tucker BAL  K 38 41 93  0 61 0-0
## 2  3 Adam Vinatieri IND  K 35 40 88  1 52 0-0
## 3  4     Nick Novak  SD  K 34 37 92  2 50 1-1

## missing first row of table
head(readHTMLTable(URL, header = TRUE)$result[1:10], 3) 
##   V1             V2  V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
## 1  1  Justin Tucker BAL  K 38 41 93  0 61 0-0
## 2  3 Adam Vinatieri IND  K 35 40 88  1 52 0-0
## 3  4     Nick Novak  SD  K 34 37 92  2 50 1-1
```

Now let's change to `header = FALSE`.  Here we find that the first row of the table is now included.

**This is the complete table.**

```
## returns complete table
head(readHTMLTable(URL, header = FALSE)$result[1:10], 3) 
##   V1                 V2  V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
## 1  1 Stephen Gostkowski  NE  K 38 41 93  0 54 1-1
## 2  1      Justin Tucker BAL  K 38 41 93  0 61 0-0
## 3  3     Adam Vinatieri IND  K 35 40 88  1 52 0-0
```

To reiterate, the complete set of data will only be returned if `header` is set to `FALSE`.

I realize it's not easy to grab HTML and XML tables perfectly.  But I'm missing the #1 kicker in the NFL in my data (insert "He's only a kicker, who cares?" jokes here).

Has anyone seen behavior like this before from an R function? Is there logic behind this scenario?  Is it specific to this particular website, perhaps?  I can test it on others, but not all of them. The `XML` package is great, but this makes me a bit uneasy.

**Session Info (partial)**

```
> sessionInfo()
## R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
## Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Comment: Just in case it's a bug, can we have `sessionInfo()` please?

Comment: No problem.  It's been added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the help for `readHTMLTable` gives the following

> **header**
>
> either a logical value indicating whether the table has column labels, e.g. the first row or a thead, or alternatively a character vector giving the names to use for the resulting columns. This can be a logical vector and the individual values will be used in turn for the different tables. This allows the caller to control whether individual tables are processed as having column names. Alternatively, one can read a specific table via the which parameter and control how that is processed with a single scalar logical.

Now, if you inspect the table you are attempting to read, you will see that the column headers are defined by two rows. In the source you will see that these are are defined in `thd1` and `thd2`.

Using `header=TRUE` or `header=NA` and there is no `thead` node  then the first row is dropped (under the assumption that it defines the column labels)

```
## a code snippet from getMethod("readHTMLTable",'XMLInternalElementNode')
 headerFromTable = FALSE
 dropFirstRow = FALSE
 if (length(header) == 1 && is.na(header)) 
    header = (xmlName(doc) %in% c("table", "tbody") && 
         ("thead" %in% names(doc) || length(getNodeSet(node, 
         "./tr[1]/th | ./tr[1]/td")) > 0))
 if (is.logical(header) && (is.na(header) || header) && 
    xmlName(node) == "table") {
      if ("thead" %in% names(node)) 
            header = node[["thead"]]
           else {
             if ("tr" %in% names(node)) 
               tmp = node[["tr"]]
               else tmp = node[["tbody"]][["tr"]]
                if (!is.null(tmp) && all(names(tmp) %in% c("text", 
                  "th"))) {
                  header = xpathSApply(tmp, "./th | ./td", xmlValue, 
                    encoding = encoding)
                  dropFirstRow = TRUE
                }
            }
        }
```

By setting `header=FALSE` you don't drop the first row.

To define the header you could

1. manually define the column labels as a character vector, or
2. use an intermediate step having parsed the HTML to extract the labels from
   the `thd1` and/or `thd2` nodes.

Comment: Nice answer. Also note that the author specifies HTML4.0 specification under references. Is the nfl table WCAG 2.0 compliant?

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you very much.  Makes good sense now.