# Dropped rows using readHTMLTable in R

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I am attempting to extract model data from NOAA using readHTMLTable.  The table I am trying to get has multiple subtitles, where each subtitle consists of a single cell spanning all columns, as far as I can tell from the HTML.  For some reason, this is causing readHTMLTable to omit the row immediately following the subtitle.  Here's code that will reproduce the issue:

```
library(XML)

url <- "http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/"
ncep.tables = readHTMLTable(url, header=TRUE)

#Find the list of real time models
for(ncep.table in ncep.tables) {
    if("grib filter" %in% names(ncep.table) & "gds-alt" %in% names(ncep.table)) {
        rt.tbl <- ncep.table
     }
}

#Here's where the problem is:
cat(paste(rt.tbl[["Data Set"]][15:20], collapse = "\n"))

#On the website, there is a model called "AQM Daily Maximum"
#between Regional Models and AQM Hourly Surface Ozone
#but it's missing now...
```

So, if you go to http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/ and look at the central table (the one with "Data Set" in the top right cell), you'll see a subtitle called "Regional Models."  The AQM Daily Maximum model immediately below the subtitle is skipped during the extraction in the code above.

I maintain the rNOMADS package in R, so if I can get this to work it will save me loads of time maintaining the package as well as keep it accurate and up to date for my users.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23230687/how-to-use-readhtmltable-without-cutting-off-first-row and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301270/readhtmltable-returns-incomplete-data-set You may find an answer in one of those two posts.

Comment: I looked into both of those.  My issue is not solved by setting header=FALSE.

Comment: The HTML on that page is is ill-formed. The "missing" row is not enclosed in "<tr>" tags as it should be. This make the table very difficult to parse. How you decide to work around that may depend on exactly what you are trying to extract from the document.

Comment: Wow. All of the usual "simple" workarounds to get past excruciatingly bad HTML tables did not work at all, but I think the answer below gets all the columns for you. Know of any way to get NOAA to actually fix the HTML on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By golly, I think I got it. You won't be able to use `readHTMLTable` (and, I now know the XML package code way more than I even did before…some serious R-fu in that code) and I'm using `rvest` simply because I mix use of XPath and CSS selectors (I ended up thinking more in XPath though). `dplyr` is only for `gimpse`.

```
library(XML)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

trim <- function(x) gsub("^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$", "", x)

# neither rvest::html nor rvest::html_session liked it, hence using XML::htmlParse
doc <- htmlParse("http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/")

ds <- doc %>% html_nodes(xpath="//table/descendant::th[@class='nomads'][1]/../../
                                            descendant::td[contains(., 'http')]/
                                            preceding-sibling::td[3]")

data_set <- ds %>% html_text() %>% trim()
data_set_descr_link <- ds %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")

freq <- doc %>% html_nodes(xpath="//table/descendant::th[@class='nomads'][1]/../../
                           descendant::td[contains(., 'hourly') or
                                          contains(., 'hours') or
                                          contains(., 'daily') or
                                          contains(., '06Z')]") %>%
  html_text() %>% trim()

grib_filter <- doc %>% html_nodes(xpath="//table/descendant::th[@class='nomads'][1]/../../
                                  descendant::td[contains(., 'http')]/preceding-sibling::td[1]") %>%
  sapply(function(x) {
    ifelse(x %>% xpathApply("boolean(./a)"),
           x %>% html_node("a") %>% html_attr("href"),
           NA)
  })

http_link <- doc %>% html_nodes("a[href^='/pub/data/']") %>% html_attr("href")

gds_alt <- doc %>% html_nodes(xpath="//table/descendant::th[@class='nomads'][1]/../../
                              descendant::td[contains(., 'http')]/following-sibling::td[1]") %>%
  sapply(function(x) {
    ifelse(x %>% xpathApply("boolean(./a)"),
           x %>% html_node("a") %>% html_attr("href"),
           NA)
  })

nom <- data.frame(data_set,
                  data_set_descr_link,
                  freq,
                  grib_filter,
                  gds_alt)

glimpse(nom)

## Variables:
## $ data_set            (fctr) FNL, GFS 1.0x1.0 Degree, GFS 0.5x0.5 Degr...
## $ data_set_descr_link (fctr) txt_descriptions/fnl_doc.shtml, txt_descr...
## $ freq                (fctr) 6 hours, 6 hours, 6 hours, 12 hours, 6 ho...
## $ grib_filter         (fctr) cgi-bin/filter_fnl.pl, cgi-bin/filter_gfs...
## $ gds_alt             (fctr) dods-alt/fnl, dods-alt/gfs, dods-alt/gfs_...

head(nom)

##                             data_set
## 1                                FNL
## 2                 GFS 1.0x1.0 Degree
## 3                 GFS 0.5x0.5 Degree
## 4                 GFS 2.5x2.5 Degree
## 5       GFS Ensemble high resolution
## 6 GFS Ensemble Precip Bias-Corrected
##
##                                             data_set_descr_link     freq
## 1                                txt_descriptions/fnl_doc.shtml  6 hours
## 2                txt_descriptions/GFS_high_resolution_doc.shtml  6 hours
## 3                    txt_descriptions/GFS_half_degree_doc.shtml  6 hours
## 4                 txt_descriptions/GFS_Low_Resolution_doc.shtml 12 hours
## 5       txt_descriptions/GFS_Ensemble_high_resolution_doc.shtml  6 hours
## 6 txt_descriptions/GFS_Ensemble_precip_bias_corrected_doc.shtml    daily
##
##                       grib_filter          gds_alt
## 1           cgi-bin/filter_fnl.pl     dods-alt/fnl
## 2           cgi-bin/filter_gfs.pl     dods-alt/gfs
## 3        cgi-bin/filter_gfs_hd.pl  dods-alt/gfs_hd
## 4       cgi-bin/filter_gfs_2p5.pl dods-alt/gfs_2p5
## 5          cgi-bin/filter_gens.pl    dods-alt/gens
## 6 cgi-bin/filter_gensbc_precip.pl dods-alt/gens_bc
```

Please make sure the columns match. I eyeballed it, but a verification would be awesome. NOTE: there may be a better way to do the `sapply`s (anyone shld feel freed to edit that in, too, crediting yourself).

It's *really* fragile code. i.e. if the format changes, it'll croak (but that's kinda true for all scraping). It should withstand them actually creating valid HTML (this is wretched HTML btw), but most of the code relies on the `http` column remaining valid since *most* of the other column extractions rely on it. Your missing model is there as well. If any of the XPath is confusing, drop a comment q and I'll try to 'splain.

Comment: Thanks - will check out soon and I'll get back to you

Comment: Truly you are a wizard - and the code works great.  A new version of rNOMADS is now on CRAN. I put an acknowledgement in the code documentation.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you just have to fix bad HTML, so you could add tr tags to the start of those rows.

```
url <- "http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/"
x <- readLines(url, encoding="UTF-8")
doc <- htmlParse(x)

# check nodes after subheaders - only 2 of 5 rows missing tr (2nd and 3rd element)
getNodeSet(doc, "//td[@colspan='7']/../following-sibling::*[1]")
# fix text - probably some way to fix XML doc too?
n <- grep(">AQM Daily Maximum<", x)
x[n] <- paste0("<tr>", x[n])
n <- grep(">RTOFS Atlantic<", x)
x[n] <- paste0("<tr>", x[n])

doc <- htmlParse(x)
## ok..
getNodeSet(doc, "//td[@colspan='7']/../following-sibling::*[1]")
readHTMLTable(doc, which=9, header=TRUE)

                                      Data Set     freq grib filter http     gds-alt
1                                 Global Models     <NA>        <NA> <NA>        <NA>
2                                           FNL  6 hours grib filter http OpenDAP-alt
3                            GFS 1.0x1.0 Degree  6 hours grib filter http OpenDAP-alt
...
16 Climate Forecast System 3D Pressure Products  6 hours grib filter http           -
17                              Regional Models     <NA>        <NA> <NA>        <NA>
18                            AQM Daily Maximum 06Z, 12Z grib filter http OpenDAP-alt
19                     AQM Hourly Surface Ozone 06Z, 12Z grib filter http OpenDAP-alt
20                                 HIRES Alaska    daily grib filter http OpenDAP-alt
```

Comment: True, but I'd like the code to remain flexible enough to capture addition and deletion of rows.  If I key it to individual models it's a bit more unstable.