# html_nodes no longer extracts table rows after website update

Tags: r, xpath, css-selectors, rvest, xml2

Some years ago I asked for help scraping the available model list on nomads.ncep.noaa.gov.  [The solution is documented here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592575/dropped-rows-using-readhtmltable-in-r)  I added the first answer into my R package [rNOMADS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rNOMADS/index.html) and have been using it ever since.  However, ever since NCEP announced they'd switch to https, the solution is failing.  I know it is not just due to the switch, because other https sites (like imdb) are still scrapeable.

I suspect they actually changed the structure of the website.  I tried to use Selectorgadget to figure out if I could just set a new css selector, but no luck.

I am at a loss...websites that use rNOMADS as a backend are failing, my users are sending me emails, and I am not sure how to fix the problem.

Any guidance is appreciated/desperately needed.

Answer (score 0):

I took a crack at it, and my guess the place to start is with [your earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592575/dropped-rows-using-readhtmltable-in-r) using XML::htmlParse

```
library(XML)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
doc_http <- htmlParse("http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/")
doc_https <- htmlParse("https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/")
```

doc_http returns

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

followed by two scripts, one a long Citrix script

doc_http returns only

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><p>https://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/</p></body></html>
```

meaning no XML. So, to the extent that RNomads html parsing relies on its XML import, it looks like you're in for some serious refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

All functions from rNOMADS are working for me changing the server URL. 
On e-mail from [NCEP.list.NOMADS-ftpprd] say:

At this time only the following website URLs have the new changes for testing:

https://nomads-cprk.ncep.noaa.gov/

https://origin.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/

New URLs are working!